# How to get "should.be.false" syntax pass jslint?

Tags: node.js, jslint, chai

I am writing JS UT for my NodeJS code. I am using [Chai](http://chaijs.com/) as the assertion library, and I prefer the *should* syntax. I also use *jslint* to check the JS file syntax, even the JS files for UT.

Now I have a problem with *jslint* and *Chai*. In *Chai*, you can use:

```
myvalue.should.be.true;
```

But *jslint* give me:

```
#1 Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression.
```

I know *jslint* comes with many options, but I just cannot find the right one to turn off this check.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It turns our **jslint** is unable to solve my problem. And due to many restrictions of jslint, I turned to [jshint](http://www.jshint.com/), and the option `expr` saved me :P

Comment: I found I needed `es5:true` too.

Comment: es5:true is default (now?)

Comment: seems like es5 is default now.

Answer (score 74):

Just to make it clear to other readers:

You can add `/*jshint expr: true*/` to the top of the test files, so it only allows it in the test files.

In the rare case that you use that kind of expressions in your code, you can add the `expr: true` option to the jshint config options.

Answer (score 15):

You can also use `myvalue.should.equal(true)` instead.